# Error convirtiendo un texto con una fecha de un excel en un campo de tipo fecha en una entidad

Tags: c#, datetime

En una azure function estoy leyendo el contenido de un excel para insertar por cada fila un registro en una base de datos y para ello por cada fila creo una entidad y luego inserto dicha entidad.

El caso es que en la entidad uno de los campos o propiedades es de tipo fecha

```
public class ConcursoExcel
{
    ...

    public DateTime FechaArchivo { get; set; }
```

y cuando estoy intentando insertar el valor del Excel

[image: excel]

[image: code]

Me salta este error

[image: error]

He intentado esto y tampoco

```
concurso.FechaArchivo = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Text);
```

Estoy usando esta libreria para analizar el excel

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
```

Alguna idea, por favor?

Un saludo

Comment: Muy probablemente, dado que usas azure entiendo, el sistema espera una fecha en formato americano (mm/dd/yyyy) en lugar de (dd/mm/yyyy). La solución en ese caso es usar [`ParseExact`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0) para pasarle el formato `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: @Pikoh la bbdd donde se insertará el registro si que está en Azure pero este error lo da mucho antes de intentar la insert. Lo da al crear la entidad que representa cada fila del Excel y en ese momento el código no sabe si la bbdd estará alojada en Azure o en Un onpremise y ni esquinera si será SQL mySQL o lo que sea

Comment: Es igual. A lo que me refería es que por los codigos de error, al estar en inglés, el formato de fecha que debe esperar es americano. Usando ParseExact lo solucionaras

Comment: Cuando esto me funcionaba las fechas entraban así"2022-03-18 00:00:00.0000000", es decir, "yyyy/MM/dd" con lo cual el formato se lo aplico así string format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH: mm: ss.ffffff"; y en prvider uso ultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; pero esta instrucción me sigue dando el mismo error concurso.FechaArchivo = DateTime.ParseExact(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Text, format,provider);

Comment: A ver..segun pones en tu captura, lo que te llega de la celda es "18/03/2022", por lo que debes hacer lo siguiente: `concurso.FechaArchivo = DateTime.ParseExact(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",provider);`